# fourier issue arising from input miscommunication

Tags: fourier-analysis

```
xdomain = Table[i , {i, -10, 10, .1}];
ListPlot[InverseFourier[
  Fourier[E^-#^2 & /@ xdomain]*E^#^2 & /@ xdomain]]
```

So I want to numerically fourier transform a function, multiply that fourier'd function by a second function, and then inverse fourier transform it.

The code above doesn't work. I get a blank graph, I think, because it doesn't properly multiply the two vectors that I commanded to multiply. I'm not sure why I can't get {a,b,c}*{1,2,3} to multiply inside my fourier function, but I have tried putting evaluate functions in different spots inside to see if that would fix it.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need brackets around `E^#^2 & /@ xdomain`
2. `ListPlot` plot only real lists so you need to apply `Re`, `Im` or `Abs`
3. `E^-#^2 & /@ xdomain` is overkill. Just `Exp[-xdomain^2]`

   ```
   xdomain = Range[-10, 10, 0.1];

   ListPlot[Re@InverseFourier[Fourier@Exp[-xdomain^2] Exp[xdomain^2]]]
   ```

[image]

P.S. It seems that you want to apply a deconvolution. The method with the inverse Fourier transform is unstable. For this purpose there is a stable build-in function [`ListDeconvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDeconvolve.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think you could help me out with using ListDeconvolve in this context?
I cannot find very much material on it's use. How do I know what method and kernel I should use to deconvolve the system?

Comment: @StevenSagona It depends on the system. Your kernel is Gaussian so `GaussianMatrix` should be a good choice. For 1D system you can use it as `GaussianMatrix[{{r}, {σ}}]` where `σ` is a standard deviation and `r` is a radius of the kernel (must be several times more than `σ`).

Answer (score 2):

Oneliners can be elegant, but sometimes they burdens Mathematica a bit too much.
Let's do it one step at the time:

```
xdomain = Table[i, {i, -10, 10, .1}];
F1= E^-#^2 & /@ xdomain; (* no problem here *)
F2 = E^+#^2 & /@ xdomain; (* no problem here *)
ftot=InverseFourier[Fourier[F1]*F2]; (* no problem here *)
```

The problem, then, is not in the multiplication. So, where is it?
Well, the problem is that ftot is a complex function.
You can plot its magnitude, its phase or its real and imaginary part. But if you try to listplot it as it is, you will get a blank graph. Perhaps you want:

```
ListPlot[Abs[ftot]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
ListPlot[Re[ftot]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]