# Time evolution of a bispinor

Tags: differential-equations, physics

The effective Hamiltonian for [polariton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton) graphene is given by:

```
ham[kx_, ky_, δ_] := 
  {{0, 0, kx - I  ky, -δ/ℏ v}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {kx + I ky, 0, 0, 0}, {-δ/ℏ v, kx + I ky, 0, 0}};
```

where `kx, ky` are wavevectors and `δ` is a constant. The initial state at `t = 0` is:

```
ψ[0] = {1, 1, -1, -1} (x + I*y) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]];
```

where `b` is the magnetic field and `v` is the drift velocity of the particle.

If one rewrites this expression interms of vector potential associated with polaritonic graphene, one obtains
 \begin{equation}
 H=\hbar\nu_{F} {\sigma}\otimes(q-\vec {A}),
 \label{eq:gauge}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{A}=-\Delta \vec S^{\prime}/\hbar\nu_{F}$.
I would like to find the time evolution for the wavefunction and plot it as a function of the coordinate and check for conservation of the particles (probability).

Here in my system the wavefunction is not a 2-component spinor, but a 4-component spinor, where the sigma and spin operators are acting on different subspaces. 
The matrix form of the Hamiltonian is written as
    \begin{equation}
    H = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 &  v ( p_x -i p_y ) & 2 \Delta \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  v ( p_x -i p_y ) \\
    v ( p_x +i p_y ) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 \Delta &  v (p_x + i p_y) & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}
According to Jens answer, the solution for the modified Hamiltonian is working perfectly.

```
eqn = Thread[
   I D[{\[Psi]1[x, y, t], \[Psi]2[x, y, t], \[Psi]3[x, y, t], \[Psi]4[
        x, y, t]}, 
      t] == {v (-I D[\[Psi]3[x, y, t], x] - D[\[Psi]3[x, y, t], y]) + 
      2 \[CapitalDelta] \[Psi]4[x, y, t], 
     v (-I D[\[Psi]4[x, y, t], x] - D[\[Psi]4[x, y, t], y]), 
     v (-I D[\[Psi]1[x, y, t], x] + D[\[Psi]1[x, y, t], y]), 
     v (-I D[\[Psi]2[x, y, t], x] + D[\[Psi]2[x, y, t], y]) + 
      2 \[CapitalDelta] \[Psi]1[x, y, t]}];
eqnWithInitial = 
  Join[eqn, 
   Thread[{\[Psi]1[x, y, 0], \[Psi]2[x, y, 0], \[Psi]3[x, y, 
       0], \[Psi]4[x, y, 0]} == {1, 1, 1, 
       1} (x + I*y) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]], 
   Thread[{\[Psi]1[-5, y, t], \[Psi]2[-5, y, t], \[Psi]3[-5, y, 
       t], \[Psi]4[-5, y, t]} == {\[Psi]1[5, y, t], \[Psi]2[5, y, 
       t], \[Psi]3[5, y, t], \[Psi]4[5, y, t]}], 
   Thread[{\[Psi]1[x, -5, t], \[Psi]2[x, -5, t], \[Psi]3[x, -5, 
       t], \[Psi]4[x, -5, t]} == {\[Psi]1[x, 5, t], \[Psi]2[x, 5, 
       t], \[Psi]3[x, 5, t], \[Psi]4[x, 5, t]}]];

v = 1;

\[CapitalDelta] = 1;

tMax = 8;

solution = 
  First@NDSolve[
    eqnWithInitial, {\[Psi]1[x, y, t], \[Psi]2[x, y, t], \[Psi]3[x, y,
       t], \[Psi]4[x, y, t]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, tMax}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];

\[CapitalPsi]1[x_, y_, t_] = \[Psi]1[x, y, t] /. solution;
\[CapitalPsi]2[x_, y_, t_] = \[Psi]2[x, y, t] /. solution;
\[CapitalPsi]3[x_, y_, t_] = \[Psi]3[x, y, t] /. solution;
\[CapitalPsi]4[x_, y_, t_] = \[Psi]4[x, y, t] /. solution;

pl = Table[
   Plot3D[{Re[\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y, t]] - 2, 
     2 + Re[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t]], Re[\[CapitalPsi]3[x, y, t]] - 1,
      1 + Re[\[CapitalPsi]4[x, y, t]]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Opacity[.9], Orange]}, 
    BoxRatios -> 1], {t, 0, tMax, tMax/20}];
ListAnimate[pl]

p2 = Table[
   Plot3D[Abs[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Orange, Directive[Opacity[.9]]}, 
    BoxRatios -> 1], {t, 0, tMax, tMax/20}];

ListAnimate[p2]
```

It seems a reasonable answer and also show the probability conservation.

```
 gridNormsB = 
 With[{delta = .1}, 
  Table[Total@
    Flatten@Table[
      Abs[\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y, t]]^2 + 
       Abs[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t]]^2 + 
       Abs[\[CapitalPsi]3[x, y, t]]^2 + 
       Abs[\[CapitalPsi]4[x, y, t]]^2, {x, -5, 5, delta}, {y, -5, 5, 
       delta}], {t, 0, tMax, 0.5}]]

(*
==>{156.28745,156.2309,156.23151,156.18101,156.1363,156.12584,156.\
08589,156.00673,155.99424}*)

ListLinePlot[gridNormsB/gridNormsB[[1]], PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 4}]

(Debug) Out[19]= {313.219, 313.16, 313.149, 313.225, 313.338, 313.49, \
313.634, 314.198, 314.658, 315.619, 323.733, 320.822, 325.094, \
327.225, 323.637, 323.981, 323.82}
```

I try to calculate the spin current for one of the wave function using the VectorPlot3D but couldn't workout. Any one know how to VectorPlot for example  `\[CapitalPsi]1[x, y, t]`.
Here is my code:

```
j[x_, y_, 
       t_] = -(I/
        2) (Conjugate[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t]]*
          D[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t], {{x, y}}] - 
         D[Conjugate[\[CapitalPsi]2[x, y, t]], {{x, y}}]*\[CapitalPsi]2[x,
            y, t]);

    VectorPlot3D[Re[j[x, y, t]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, tMax}]
```

Comment: Does `NDSolve` not do what you want?

Comment: yes, NDSolve probably the best way.

Comment: @user34056 Is your Hamiltonian time-independent? If so you can diagonalize the Hamiltonian and do the time evolution analytically.

Comment: @ xslittlegrass yes it's time independent.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I'm looking for the time evolution not the eigenvalues.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I still don't see how to use NDSolve

Comment: This is very closely related to [Animated Wave propagation using split operator method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80996/245), and similarly to that question, here we have mainly issues related to setting up the physics problem correctly. As in that question, you have a position dependent wave function (`y` is a coordinate), and the Hamiltonian is written in Fourier space. But your initial state is unphysical because it's not differentiable at `y = 0`, so I wouldn't know what to do with this. Otherwise, the method of my linked answer should work.

Comment: @Jens, I tryed with the above link but couldn't manage it. I now changed the initial wavefunction.

Comment: @user34056 per your comment above, if you know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors than you know the time evolution operator for all times.  Also, I'm having trouble understanding your basis functions in the position space.  Are all four basis functions the same?  Your Hilbert space has four basis functions, but in the position space it looks like they are all `(x + I*y) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]`

Comment: The Hamiltonian is also missing a term. As I said, you should first make sure that the physics problem is set up correctly - until then, it's not a *Mathematica* issue.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Animated Wave propagation using split operator method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80996/245) because I can easily produce solutions by following the same method as there. Just replace the `kx`, `ky` by their operator form in the position basis, correct the Hamiltonian to be hermitian, choose numerical values for the parameters, specify periodic boundary conditions, and use `NDSolve` exactly as in the linked answer.

Comment: @Jens, thank you so much for your comment. The same Hamiltonian as in Eq. 6 in the recent paper [http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.04009.pdf](http://example.com)

Comment: @Jens, you are right, it is exactly as in the linked answer. I am trying to plot for the spin current for one of the wave function but not working out with my code. any comments would be greatly appreciated