# How to do a Inverse Discrete Fourier which contains frequency component?

Tags: fourier-analysis, discrete

I need do a integral is shown below
[image]
It coulde be writen as bellow which `kz` is related to `kx` and `ky` :
[image: ![enter image description here]

I used FourierTransform. But because I need to calculate multiple iterations of ∆z，time gets super long and it did't work right. So I want to use Discrete Fourier to reduce time. But I don't know how to deal kz. My idea is to create a matrix of frequency variables to represent it, but I don't know its frequency range and how to use matrix to represent the frequency in `InverseFourierTransform`.

That's what I have tried. The problem happened on :

```
w = 1;
initialEi[x_] = E^(-x^2/w^2);
InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[initial, x, kx]*
          E^(I*Sqrt[k^2 - kx^2]*Δz), kx, x]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

For a function like this, `InverseFourierTransform` didn't work.

A simplified version of the entire code is shown below:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
λ = 1.2398/10; 
k = 2*(Pi/λ); 
w = 1;
initialEi[x_] = E^(-x^2/w^2);

Beam[initial_, Δz_] := 
 InverseFourierTransform [FourierTransform[initial, x, kx]*
           E^(I*Sqrt[k^2 - kx^2]*Δz), kx, x]
BeamPropagate[initial2_, Distance_, Δz_] := 
  NestList[Beam, initial2, Ceiling[Distance/Δz]];
listofBeam = Block[
  {x = 1, Δz = .05, Distance = 1}, 
  BeamPropagate[initialEi[x], Distance, Δz]
  ]
```

This is actually a beam propagation problem, the result I want to get is a graph as below, given the initial state of E[x,z] at z, we can deduce the state of the light wave at nΔz. This method of deriving beam propagation is called Multi- slice Method. I'm not a theoretical professional, so I have a lot of confusion about the implementation of these formulas. If anyone knows this stuff, I'd really appreciate it if you could give me some advices.

By the way this is the [Peltio's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34347/76643) I referenced about this problem.

[image]

Comment: Show code as text, not graphics.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you for your reply, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a very basic question. You just have to study the definition of the discrete Fourier transform and then use `Fourier` and `InverseFourier`.The frequency parameter matrix in the discrete inverse Fourier transform can be expressed by the matrix related to the spatial coordinates.The definition of a matrix is as follows：

```
xStart = -50;
xEnd = 50;
Δx = .1;

Nx = (xEnd - xStart)/Δx + 1;
kxStart = -π/Δx;
kxEnd = π/Δx;
Δkx = (2 π)/(xEnd - xStart);

x = Table[i, {i, xStart, xEnd, Δx}];
kx = Table[j, {j, kxStart, kxEnd, Δkx}];
```

One thing to be aware of is the relationship between the angular and spatial frequencies, because they differ by a multiple of 2π, which may affect the accuracy of your final calculation. Don't ask me how I know that, as someone who gets a headache from looking at mathematical formulas.